# Why are total only calculated in one dimension wiht margins=True in pandas.pivot_table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Examples for `pandas.pivot_table` show totals being calculated for rows and columns, but for me totals are only calculated for rows.

I can reproduce this behavior with different DataFrames on this setup:

Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.7, Pandas 0.24.2

```py
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame([
    ["sec", "2019-01", 1], 
    ["sec", "2019-02", 2], 
    ["maint","2019-02", 1], 
    ["maint","2019-03",3]
])
print(df)
# If not passing arguments as lists, behavior is essentially the same
p = df.pivot_table(
    index=[0], columns=[1], values=[2], 
    aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0., 
    margins=True
)
print(p)
```

Output:

```
       0        1  2
0    sec  2019-01  1
1    sec  2019-02  2
2  maint  2019-02  1
3  maint  2019-03  3

            2                    
1     2019-01 2019-02 2019-03 All
0                                
maint       0       1       3   4
sec         1       2       0   3
All         0       0       0   7
```

As you can see in the last row, the aggregation is not applied to the columns (except for the last one) and values are just 0.

As suggested by many examples I would have expected the `pivot_table` to produce this result:

```
            2                    
1     2019-01 2019-02 2019-03 All
0                                
maint       0       1       3   4
sec         1       2       0   3
All         1       3       3   7
```

Did I do or understand something wrong? Or might this be a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in pandas that only looks to occur with numeric columns and `margins=True`.  A workaround is to temporarily cast numeric column names to strings:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd; pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.24.2'

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([
   ...:     ["sec", "2019-01", 1],
   ...:     ["sec", "2019-02", 2],
   ...:     ["maint","2019-02", 1],
   ...:     ["maint","2019-03",3]])

In [3]: # wrong output with numeric columns
   ...: df.pivot_table(index=[0], columns=[1], values=[2],
   ...:                aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0., margins=True)
Out[3]:
            2
1     2019-01 2019-02 2019-03 All
0
maint       0       1       3   4
sec         1       2       0   3
All         0       0       0   7

In [4]: # correct output with string columns
   ...: df.columns = df.columns.map(str)
   ...: df.pivot_table(index=['0'], columns=['1'], values=['2'],
   ...:                aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0., margins=True)
Out[4]:
            2
1     2019-01 2019-02 2019-03 All
0
maint       0       1       3   4
sec         1       2       0   3
All         1       3       3   7
```